# How to work around with App Script API with Service account

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, http-status-code-403, service-accounts, google-apps-script-api

I want to call Apps Script API in my app, it works fine with web user authentication but has a 403 error when I change to using a service account.

I discovered that the reason is that the Apps Script API does not work with service accounts according to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts/).

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this workaround is included in your expected result, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60653714

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful, it's the one I've been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I flagged it as a duplicate question.